# Symmetric matrices $M$ such that $x,y\geq 0$ implies $(x^t M y)^2\geq (x^t M x)(y^t M y)$

Tags: matrices, inequality

Is there a name for $n$-by-$n$ symmetric matrices $M$ such that for all $n$-dimensional non-negative-valued vectors $x,y$ we have
$$(x^t M y)^2 \geq (x^t M x)(y^t M y)?$$

In particular I am interested in the case where the entries of $M$ are non-negative and $M$ has zeros on its diagonal. A matrix like this appears in a proof of the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality. An example in each dimension is given by the matrix $B$ defined by $$B_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $i\neq j$}\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Indeed let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$, and assume without loss of generality that $\sum_ix_i=\sum_iy_i=1$. Then $(x^tB y)^2=(1-x^ty)^2\geq (1-x^tx)(1-y^ty)=(x^t B x)(y^t B y)$.

Comment: So all $x_i \geq 0$ and all $y_i \geq 0?$

Comment: Yes, all the components of $x$ and of $y$ are non-negative.